# Jquery interrupt cascading image load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

```
// Data array of pages    
var arrPages = [];    
arrPages[0] = new Array (2578, '1.jpg', false);    
arrPages[1] = new Array (2579, '2.jpg', false);    
arrPages[2] = new Array (2580, '3.jpg', false);    
arrPages[3] = new Array (2581, '4.jpg', false);    
arrPages[4] = new Array (2582, '5.jpg', false);    

        // Generates the page
    function generatePage(pageID){
        var newImage;
        // Check not already loaded
        if(pageID >= 0 && pageID < arrPages.length && !arrPages[pageID][2])
        {
            newImage = $('<img class="pageImg" id="imgA' + pageID + '" src="
                      <%=strProjectPath%>/pages/thumbnails/' + 
                       arrPages[pageID][1] + '" alt="Page image" />');
            $('#page' + pageID).append(newImage);                                
            $('#imgA' + pageID).load(function() {
                alert("loaded");
                arrPages[pageID][2] = true;
                generatePage(pageID + 1, false);
            });
        }
    }

    // Load first page
    $(document).ready(function() {
        updateOrientation();
        generatePage(0);
    });
```

As you can see, on page load it starts cascading through the array loading the image once the first one loads.

My question is, if there are a lot of pages (say 100), the preloader might get to say index 10, but then if the user skips to view index 85 the preloader needs to stop loading from index 10, and start again at index 85.

I'm not quite sure how to stop the image loading and then start it up again at a different index.

Comment: Is it OK to start loading index 85 while image 10 is still loading? or do you must wait for image 10 to finish loading before loading image 85?

Comment: It's for a mobile application, so 85 should load first as it's the one being viewed immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement this is using storing a "version" number, that will be increased every time the user navigates to a different page.

Declare a global variable:

```
curVersion = 0;
```

Inside your loop:

```
var func = function(ver){
    return function() {
        alert("loaded");
        arrPages[pageID][2] = true;

        //Check if we still need to casecade
        if(curVersion == ver) {
            generatePage(pageID + 1, false);
        }
    };
}(curVersion);

$('#imgA' + pageID).load(func);
```

When the user navigates to a different page, or should you want to stop the cascading simply increment `curVersion`, then (optionally) call `generatePage(85)` to start again from that page.